# How to bind textboxes based on selection of dropdownlist in asp.net?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have table named tbl_Employee with columns Employee_name,Emp_ID,Emp_Salary,Emp_State,Emp_Mobile Number.

I have an aspx page where I used a dropdownlist and binded with the dtabase which when we click we get all Employee name from that dropdownlist.

Here is the code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT EmpId, Name FROM tblEmployee"))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                ddlEmployee.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                ddlEmployee.DataTextField = "Name";
                ddlEmployee.DataValueField = "EmpId";
                ddlEmployee.DataBind();
                con.Close();

            }
        }
        ddlEmployee.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select Employee--", "0"));
    }
}
```

On the same page I have 3 textbox named txtname, txtMobile, and txtState. So I want to bind the value from database to those textbox on selection of particular employee to that drop downlist.

For Ex. If have selected Empname 'ABC' those 3 textboxes should be bind with the value of ABC name, ABC mobile and his State.
How do I do that? Do I have to use Jquery or javascript?

Comment: @James Z Thanks for correcting!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to show employee details while `ddlEmployee` select change, so suppose you have `ddlEmployee` like :

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEmployee" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                onselectedindexchanged="ddlEmployee_SelectedIndexChanged">
 </asp:DropDownList>
```

So it be done in `onselectedindexchanged` of your DropDown Like:

```
protected void ddlEmployee_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Mobile,Name,State FROM tblEmployee where EmpId= @empId"))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empId", ddlEmployee.SelectedValue);
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if(reader.Read())
                {
                    lblName.Text = reader["Name"].ToString();
                    lblEmail.Text = reader["Mobile"].ToString();
                    lblState.Text = reader["State"].ToString();
                }
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception s)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("Error Occured " + s.Message);
    }
}
```