# Joining two ID's together to get another Column Result

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I am using Windows Form and C# and an SQlite Database. I have a Combo Box with the Player's Name and below i have a textbox which i need to fill with the Overall Rating

I have two tables named Player and Player_Attributes. Now i need to join the Player_Api_ID so that i can get the Overall Rating Result from the Player_Attributes table according to the Player's Name found in the Player Table. Can someone show me how the statement can be done? Thanks

Player Table1

[image: Player Table1]

Player_Attributes Table

[image]

**UI**

[image]

**Dropdown Code**

```
private void playersListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string filename = @"C:\Users\nicho\Documents\nicholas2ndyearproject\database.sqlite";
            var conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + filename + ";Version=3;");
            {
                using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT player_name, Player_Attributes.sprint_speed FROM Player JOIN Player_Attributes ON Player.player_api_id = Player_Attributes.player_api_id;"))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    conn.Open();
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@player_api_id", playersListBox.SelectedValue);
                    SQLiteDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    if (reader.Read())
                    {
                        txtRating.Text = reader["rating"].ToString();
                    }
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: so you need SQL query?

Comment: Yes.. i'm using SQLite

Comment: Note that if for 1 `Player_Api_ID` there is only 1 `Player_fifa_Api_ID` and for 1 `Player_fifa_Api_ID` there is only 1 `Player_Api_ID`, then the table `Player_Attributes Table` is poorly designed. You are duplicating informations.

Comment: What have you done so far ? I see no query that fetches such informations

Comment: @Cid, He is expecting that query only.

Comment: Then SO isn't the site he is looking for. That's not a free-code service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this is what you want if my assumption is correct.

```
SELECT  FirstName, LastName, Player_Attributes.overall_rating
FROM Player JOIN Player_Attributes
ON Player.Player_api_id= Player_Attributes.Player_api_id
```

I hope your overall logic is wrong - playersListBox_SelectedIndexChanged() in this change event you needs to bind all the values. 
for example.

```
txtRating.Text = queryresultobject.overall_rating.value;
txtName.Text = queryresultobject.Name;
```

Like above onchange event you needs to bind the values. First go through how to bind values onchange of dropdown in asp.net

[This link will give you more clarity on how to implement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48238468/how-to-bind-textboxes-based-on-selection-of-dropdownlist-in-asp-net)

Edited - changed join logic

Comment: if any fields needs to be added or removed you can do it .

Comment: Thanks, the Overall rating is from the Player_Attributes table but

Comment: Does it still need to be placed there?

Comment: @Jhonny Please check the answer now

Comment: The query will give you the result but binding and all you needs to take care of it in .NET properly.

Comment: That's my problem now cause the rating is not displaying in the textbox

Comment: could you please show us the screenshot of UI, Because i am not able to understand clearly, You want to show the rating in a textbox when user select the value from list right?

Comment: Where there is speed take it as the Overall Rating

Comment: i need to show the rating according to the player selected

Comment: txtRating.Text = this one you needs to map with the data which comes from query overall_rating attribure

Comment: I updated the question with what i tried now. Thanks

Comment: It's working now but only shows the Rating of the first player in the table even if player is changed

Comment: @Jhonny Please check your code properly, You needs to handle the event handling properly else it wont work. Please go through the link and learn how to handle the onchange event for dropdown in asp.net.

Comment: Yes i checked the code from there and changed a bit cause mine is Sqlite but it's not updating only shows the first player data

Comment: I just changed -- string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString; with the filename

Comment: debug and check what is happening when you change the dropdown, I cant explain more than this mate, I am sorry for that.

Comment: @Jhonny You needs to change the code for sure. But make sure before by debugging it modify it accordingly. The reason for not changing the value from second request is that event is not firing up so debug and understand why its not firing